# AFHTTPClient, default response using getPath: parameters: success: failure:

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking version 1. I've subclassed `AFHTTPClient`, and I'm using a `sharedManager` to use it with `getPath: parameters: success: failure:`

For every request, I want to check if the user is logged out (if they have, then I return them to the log-in screen). I get `logged-in` as a field in the JSON returned. How can I check the JSON is success for every request for this field, without having to write it each time in the success block? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a userDefaults variable and change it if the user presses corresponding button(s) in the application.

```
- (BOOL)isLoggedIn {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"logged-in"];
}
```

By the way, if you use AFHTTPClient you should be ready to copy-paste some code in every success block like parsing responseObject and access to it's fields (if necessary). This is the main disadvantage of this approach.